# Form only posts regular HTML inputs (not posting XML fields)

Tags: joomla-3.x, form

I have a form (with XML fields) and it posts only the hidden fields type and other regular HTML inputs. It doesn't post the XML form.

My form

```
<form action="<?php echo JUri::base().'getpost'; ?>" method="post" name="adminForm" id="adminForm">

  <?php $this->form->renderFieldset('fieldset') ?>

  <input type="hidden" name="type" value="Gallery" />
  <input type="hidden" name="year" value="2020" />

 <button type="submit" name="submit">Send</button>

</form>
```

My XML:

```
<form>
 <fieldset  name="fieldset">
   <field
     name="height"
     type="text"
     label="Height"
   />

   <field
     name="name"
     type="text"
     label="Name"
   />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

The XML form data isn't being sent to post only regular HTML fields. Any explanation? I'm posting the form to another view; could it be the problem?

Comment: usually you set $this->form = (something that loads the form) and then $this->form->renderFieldset(...)

Comment: Yeah i have that in my original code. It used to work but not anymore. Only hidden inputs are posted or normal HTML inputs.The form is being displayed without any erros.

Comment: I'm posting it to another view. Does it make any difference? Like would i have to reference the form or something?

Comment: So i found out that my XML isn't being posted because i'm posting it to a nother view. How can i solve it? Should i create a new layout in the same view instead?

Comment: Sorry Thiago, I'm not really understanding what your setup is. Usually for each form you'd have separate model, view and layout files. If you have the same form, but it's displayed in 2 different ways, then you can use the same model and view, and have 2 different layout files.

Comment: Well, i have a form that posts to a page , this page gets the data from this form to display in this new page and this page also has a form (i could use the same form rendering independente fieldsets). They have their MVC each page. The problem is that the XML fields aren't being posted. Only the regular HTML inputs. Is that because i'm posting the form to another view?

Comment: Like my view `Gallery` has a form, then i post this form to a new page (a new view) `Registration`, this new view will get the data from the other view `Gallery` to complete the registration proccess, the problem is that only regular HTML inputs are being sent to this new view called `Registration`. I have tried even `echo $_POST['name']` it says undefined index whereas those inputs who aren't XML fields (normal/regular/conventional HTML inputs) they are posted normally. So i believe it has something to do with the views and xml, i believe it ahs to be, somehow, declared in the other view?

Comment: Plus how can i post the form to a different layout? I have tried this, i even tried to access the layout directly; it gives me a 404 error. Do i have to register the layout in my view or something? How can i do it?  I already have the layout file.

Comment: It sounds as if you have a registration process which occurs in 2 steps. What you can do is display the first form, then in the controller handling the POST save the user-entered data in the session (using https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_user_state_variables) and redirect to the 2nd webpage. In the 2nd step you can load the 2nd form from its XML, then add the 1st form (see https://docs.joomla.org/Advanced_form_guide#Adding_Fields_via_form_definition) then prepopulate the data in the 1st form fields using data retrieved from the session (user state).

Comment: To use a different layout you can add &layout=xxx into the URL. Or you can set up a menu item to point to a different layout if you create an XML corresponding to the layout in the same layout directory. Eg look at default.php and default.xml in Joomla layout directories.

Comment: I did it. i created a new layout file; i was running into this problem so i realised i could create a new layout file so i did it but it gives me a 404 error. The layout file is in the same folder as my `Gallery` view in tmpl subfolder. `views/gallery/tmpl/registration`. I tried `[root]/index.php?option=com_gallery&view=gallery&layout=registration`. So was it supposed to work? If so, i don't know what that could be.

Comment: @RobbieJackson i simply forgot to add this line: `$data  = $input->get('jform', array(), 'array')` before getting the data from the XML form. HAHAH as i'm new in Joomla, this kind of thing will happen frequently so bare with me.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!